# Text automatically double spaced when there are no spaces or breaks in the code

Tags: html, css, whitespace, line-breaks, margins

My output has a large space between "specs" and "black metal" and on top of and below "This is Vudu's..." How do I change that?

```html
<span style="font-size:12px">This is Vudu's newest product...</span>
<h3><strong>Specs</strong></h3>
<main>
  <ul>
    <li>black metal</li>
    <li>aircraft grade material</li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

I have tried specifying margins with pixels and percentage but neither do anything. I have used two different programs, am currently working on w3schools, but there is always the same result.

Comment: It's a CSS issue, so you need to post the CSS involved.

Comment: If you use you browsers devtools inspect facility you can see exactly what CSS is being applied to each element and where it has come from. If you haven’t applied any of your own CSS then you’ll find the gaps are from the browsers default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Headings and ul have default marging set already in browser. So you need to reset it to 0 like this. (It is not vudu thing...)

```css
h3{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
  <span style="font-size:12px">This is Vudu's newest product...</span>
  <h3><strong>Specs</strong></h3>
  <main>
    <ul>
      <li>black metal</li>
      <li>aircraft grade material</li>
    </ul>
  </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to override two elements the H3 and the UL default styles.
The default CSS for an `<h3>` element is:

```
display: block; 
font-size: 1.17em; 
margin-top: 1em; 
margin-bottom: 1em; 
margin-left: 0; 
margin-right: 0; 
font-weight: bold;
```

Default style for (in chrome at least) for `<ul` is

```
display: block;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-block-start: 1em;
margin-block-end: 1em;
margin-inline-start: 0px;
margin-inline-end: 0px;
padding-inline-start: 40px;
```

Here I include but commented out the defaults and then the part I need to override for the issue at hand using a class for each element since I find using an element name like `<h3` or `<ul` in my CSS simply applies to too much HTML for my taste.

```css
body {
  /* the default for my browser as it is for most */
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* the default *
h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.17em;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
*/


/* the part I need to override */
.specs-heading {
  margin-block-end: 0em;
}

/* the default *
ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
*/

/* the part I need to override */
.my-list {
  margin-block-start: 0em;
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size:12px">This is Vudu's newest product...</span>
<h3 class="specs-heading"><strong>Specs</strong></h3>
<main>
  <ul class="my-list">
    <li>black metal</li>
    <li>aircraft grade material</li>
  </ul>
</main>
```